# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for localhost

Tags: java, servlets

My Code

```
 Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt;
    String user = "test";
    String password = "test1";
    String url = "localhost;
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
              HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);


try {
    try {  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String query = "select * from dataTable";
}........
```

The Errors i am getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for localhost
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.phidget22.ShowDatabase.doGet(ShowDatabase.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

i have also got the mysql connector jar in my referenced library, WEB-INF folder and tomcat library folder. i am not sure why it is giving me these errors again and again.

Comment: Does the URL match the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html)?

Comment: you haven't included the .jar library file for it

Comment: You mean the jar file name should be "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"? My file name is something like com.mysql.jdbc.Driver5489.jar

Comment: you wouldn't get this error if it was included correctly.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Comment: your url should be something like this- `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db`

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte so should i change the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have `String url = "localhost;` it must be edited as

`String url = "localhost";`

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/(your db name)";
```

Comment: Thanks but no thats not the problem , it is just to make you understand my code

Comment: Is your code missing the jdbc:mysql:// part of the URL?

Comment: i have tried to put jdbc:mysql:// and now i get java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'test'@'cpc102022-bagu16-2-0-cust362.1-3.cable.virginm.net' (using password: YES)

Comment: is your mysql password correct test1 for username test?

Comment: yes it is absolutely correct i have checked it very carefully

Comment: @Ng21 did you import java.sql.Connection; ?

Comment: yes i have already included : import java.sql.Connection;

Comment: What is the IDE you are using ?

Comment: it is Eclipse EE oxygen

Comment: sorry Jee oxygen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157684/discussion-between-nisal-edu-and-ng21).